# change redirect path after login and sign in with Google using Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I have this code in am directory app/HTTP/controllers/LoginWithGoogle.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Laravel\Socialite\Facades\Socialite;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Exception;

class LoginWithGoogleController extends Controller
{
     public function redirectToGoogle()
    {
        return Socialite::driver('google')->redirect();
    }

    public function handleGoogleCallback()
    {
        try {

            $user = Socialite::driver('google')->user();

            $finduser = User::where('google_id', $user->id)->first();

            if($finduser){

                Auth::login($finduser);

                return redirect()->intended('dashboard');

            }else{
                $newUser = User::create([
                    'name' => $user->name,
                    'email' => $user->email,
                    'google_id'=> $user->id,
                    'password' => encrypt('123456dummy')
                ]);

                Auth::login($newUser);

                return redirect()->intended('dashboard');
            }

        } catch (Exception $e) {
            dd($e->getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

I want to change `return redirect()->intended('dashboard'); and return redirect()->intended('dashboard');`  to the dirictory resorces/views/index.blade.php How can I do if please help me I am new in web development.How can I do if please help me I am new in web development .How can I do if please help me I am new in web development .How can I do if please help me I am new in web development .How can I do if please help me I am new in web development .

Answer (score 0):

`return redirect()->route('home');`
Or what ever you named your route for that view
But you will want to make sure you have a auth middleware on the route. e.g.

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('index');
})->name('home')->middleware('auth');
```

Answer (score 0):

As Micheal says you can use `return redirect()->route('home')` instead of `return redirect()->intended('dashboard');`

and for simplicity you can use `Route::view('/', 'index')->name('home');` in your **web.php**

Also if you want to pass static values you can pass that in the third parameter as an array

```
Route::view('/', 'index', ['title' => 'Welcome to home'])->name('home');
```